# What is one word for truncating a string and adding "..." at the end of it?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

In software apps sometimes a string's length is greater than its container so the string is truncated.

Example:

> "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"

becomes

> "The quick brown fox jum..."

There is a single word for this but I can't remember it.

Comment: Not sure that this is a correct use of the term in English but "elided"'seems quite a popular term for it in Software projects from a quick web search. [example 1](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-6233?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) and [example 2](https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/ui/base/text/text_elider.h)

Comment: you're probably looking for elision, • [ count noun ] an omission of a passage in a book, speech, or film: the movie's elisions and distortions have been carefully thought out.

Comment: If you happen to be describing this for software documentation, just say that text-overflow was ellipsis. In that context, it'll be more clear than using a more obscure word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Ellipsis I believe.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Comment: Ellipsis is the name of the symbol. It is also a word for sentences with important parts missing. Neither are quite the process of truncating and applying ellipsis, but I doubt there is much better in a single word. Maybe that is a modern usage of the word which I'm not aware of, though. It would be a natural extension. Elide is too general. I think either ellipsis or truncation is fine. People will know what you mean.

Comment: @DanSheppard: originally _ellipsis_ is the name of a process, by which things are omitted. It is by extension used for a symbol (...) which is used to show that ellipsis has taken place.

Comment: @ColinFine As I understand it ellipsis is the property of a sentence with elision (including for stylistic or rhetorical effect)? That could be represented in a number of ways, including with the ellipsis symbol, but not necessarily: "I have two cows, you three, him none: how is this fair?". I don't think there's a word for eliding with an ellipsis symbol.

Comment: glance in a dictionary to get the definition of a word

Comment: @Fattie Glance in several to get something more like the true picture.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

ellipsize, a neologism, means to shorten text using an ellipsis, i.e. three dots ... or more commonly ligature …, to stand in for the omitted bits.

Comment: A neologism is a word newly accepted into the lexis (and in reasonably common use; an entry in a reputable dictionary would be evidence for this) and not a DIY suggestion, however reasonable looking and in line with however productive a pattern. Have you evidence that 'ellipsize' is actually a word, Meenohara?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes it is an actual word in tech and used in android app development(can be there in other development areas too)
Moreover the OP mentioned "software" in "In software apps sometimes a string's length is greater than its container so the string is truncated."
The question itself is tech sounding

Comment: Then you need to add a corroborating reference or two (linked and correctly attributed) to your answer. And not merely one of say ten Google results (114 000 would be a different matter). Unsupported answers tend to come across as (and may be) nothing more than blinkered opinion. //  Though there _is_ a reference to computing, the 'computing' tag is _not_ invoked, so the overall flavour is general English. Are there non-tech examples? Many?

Comment: There are no non tech examples I know of but please read the original question. The OP is in fact asking for a tech word.

Comment: Not in the title question. And a request for a technical usage must be (a) ultimately referencing one that a general English audience is familiar with and (b) accompanied by the 'technical' tag. This question doesn't have the required tag, and this answer isn't one in common English usage among a general audience. Note that providing an example from say the business world doesn't  automatically mean that business jargon is being requested. Business (tech / sport / art ... people also use standard English words, constructions, punctuation.... (And thode ellipses weren't tech-jargon related).